# Advanced Custom Fields not displaying

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, customization

my php skills are pretty limited and I am pretty much stuck with the following issue.

Why is my Custom Field (placed at the bottom) not showing up after the posts blocks?
Here is what my code looks like:

```
<!-- 3 COLUMN POSTS -->
<!-- FIRST COLUMN BELOW -->
<div class="row"><!-- Foundation .row start -->
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 columns post-column">
        <h3>What's Going On</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="homepage-posts">
        <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns post-column">
            <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
            <?php
            $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=8&posts_per_page=1' );
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
            ?>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <div class="news-excerpt"><p><?php echo excerpt(100); ?></p>
        </div>
        <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 150);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">Read more &raquo;</a></p><br><br>

    </div>

    <!-- SECOND COLUMN BELOW -->
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns post-column">
        <h2>Recent Jobs</h2>
        <?php
        $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=5' );
        while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
        ?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <div class="news-excerpt"><p><?php echo excerpt(100); ?></p>
    </div>
    <p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 150);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">Read more &raquo;</a></p><br><br>

</div>

<!-- THIRD COLUMN BELOW -->
<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns post-column">
    <h2>Resources</h2>
    <?php
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=10&posts_per_page=5' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
    ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<div class="news-excerpt"><p><?php echo excerpt(100); ?></p>
</div>
<p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 150);?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">Read more &raquo;</a></p><br><br>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php the_field('about_blurb'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Where does it show up?

Comment: It doesn't show up at all. Something is conflicting between the 3 columns and the Custom Field at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Your custom loop `$catquery` will override the "current" post, and so `the_field` will operate on the last post of that loop.

Call `wp_reset_postdata()` right after your loop is finished (after `endwhile;`). This will restore the post global to the true "current" post.